# Taking a single ODE step

Tags: python, scipy, ode

Is it possible to take a single step with a scipy ODE integrator? I am aware of the `step` argument to `scipy.integrate.ode.integrate`, but I can't figure out to set the `t` argument such that it is guaranteed to take exactly one full step. The obvious choice is `t=inf`, but that gives an ODE failure::

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
obj = ode(lambda t, y: -y)
obj.set_initial_value(1)
y_new = obj.integrate(inf, step=True)
```

-

```
 DVODE--  At T (=R1) and step size H (=R2), the    
       corrector convergence failed repeatedly     
       or with abs(H) = HMIN   
      In above,  R1 =  0.0000000000000D+00   R2 =             Infinity
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.py:869: UserWarning: 
vode: Repeated convergence failures. (Perhaps bad Jacobian supplied or 
wrong choice of MF or tolerances.)
  'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
```

If I use `t=0`, then the ODE does not advance at all. I can chose a finite positive number, but is that guaranteed to take a full step and step over `t` if `t` is smaller than the full step? I am writing a general library and do not know what a typical step size will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tests and verified that that setting `step=True` and `t` equal to any positive finite number will take exactly one step. It will step over `t` if `t` is smaller than the next step.

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
obj = ode(lambda t, y: -y)
obj.set_initial_value(1)
while obj.t < 1:
    y_new = obj.integrate(1, step=True)
print(obj.t) # prints 1.037070648009345
```

One thing to note is that the adaptive step size guesses the initial step size based on a particular fraction of `t`. Choosing a smaller `t` causes it take a smaller first step. This is why `inf` fails and why there is no value of `t` that will cause the integrator to step over `t` in the first step.

Answer (score -1):

Numerical integrators are not really designed in terms of fixed steps, so it is hard, if even possible, to achieve your goal that way. You may find a way by fudging with the maximum and minimum step size parameters.
However, if you want to inspect what the integrator is doing, or attach some logging function to the integrator process, you can do it: use [`set_solout()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.set_solout.html#scipy.integrate.ode.set_solout).

The function (`callable` object) that you pass as argument to `set_solout()` will be called at each step of integration.

Comment: I am not looking for a fixed step. But even variable-step solvers still have steps (the function passed to `set_selout` is called each after each one). I'll try to return `-1` from the selout function to do what I want.

Comment: Yes, that was the point of my answer: `set_selout` is what you probably wanted, but your question was about performing a single step with the integrator.

Comment: "Numerical integrators are not really designed in terms of fixed steps"
 - it depends on the method. The explicit [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), for example, use a fixed step size.